# Add listener to a variable in a global instance of a class

Tags: class, swift3, swift-protocols, xcode8

I have a User Class which holds the details of that particular user, authentication status and a flag that tells me wether or not my user's data has been retrieved:

```
// Users class

class user_Global {

   static let shared_Instance = user_Global()
   var is_Retrieved : Bool = false
   var is_Authenticated : Bool = false
   var user : users_Status = users_Status.init(name: "Global user", is_Master: false, EY_ID : "N/A", ey_Email : "N/A", UUID : "N/A")
    }

// Structure

struct users_Status{

var user_Name : String!
var is_User_Master : Bool!
var user_EY_Email : String!
var user_UUID : String!
var user_EY_ID : String!

init(name : String!, is_Master : Bool!, EY_ID : String! ,ey_Email : String!, UUID : String!){

    self.user_Name = name
    self.is_User_Master = is_Master
    self.user_EY_Email = ey_Email
    self.user_UUID = UUID
    self.user_EY_ID = EY_ID

   }

}
```

Going further in my app, i have few functionalities that i only allow for the authenticated user, The problem is that this status can change any time. How do i add a listener to that variable i.e `is_Authenticated` in my ***`user_Global.shared_Instance..`*** to perform an operation on my subsequent classes.

I did think of using protocol-delegate method but couldn't get it operational. Somehow my protocol conforming classes are not calling the function of the protocol.

**EDIT 1**

```
class user_Global {

var refresh_Delegate : user_Data_Refresh!

static let shared_Instance = user_Global()
var is_Retrieved : Bool = false
var is_Authenticated : Bool = false{

    didSet{

        print(oldValue)
        print(is_Authenticated)

    }

}
var user : users_Status = users_Status.init(name: "Global user", is_Master: false, EY_ID : "N/A", ey_Email : "N/A", UUID : "N/A"){

    didSet{

        if user.is_User_Master == true{

            print("The user has MASTER Permissions")
            user_Data_Refresh.refresh_User_State() // This is the line where is get an error

        }else{

            print("Master Auth was terminated!")

        }
    }

 }


}

// Protocol : 

protocol user_Data_Refresh {

   func refresh_User_State()

}
```

**PS:** `user` is updated once i retrieve the value from my Database. To confirm that data is already retrieved `is_Retrieved` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property observers for this:

```
class user_Global {

    static let shared_Instance = user_Global()
    var is_Retrieved : Bool = false
    var is_Authenticated : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
    var user : users_Status = users_Status.init(name: "Global user", is_Master: false, EY_ID : "N/A", ey_Email : "N/A", UUID : "N/A")
}
```

**Update**
You have a protocol definition there and `user_Global` defines a delegate which conforms to this protocol `var refresh_Delegate : user_Data_Refresh!`(PS: Delegates usually are optionals).
The problem in the mentioned line:

```
user_Data_Refresh.refresh_User_State()
```

is that you do not use the delegate object to call the function, but instead you use its type, which is wrong.
Replace it with

```
refresh_Delegate.refresh_User_State()
```

and it should work.

Note: It looks like you are moving to Swift from backend development or C/C++ or something like that. Please take your time to revise [Swift API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) to get in touch more with naming conventions. Your code is hardly readable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply please see the edit. I want to call a protocol function , but i am unable to. I have upvoted your answer.. I am having a problem how to make my other classes conforming to my protocol execute the delegate functions. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Updated the answer.